# Python If statement in for loop - list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists. List A and List B. The values from List B are also in List A, but the values from List A are not all in List B. So List A is longer.

I want to check if a value from List A is in List B and if not, insert it at the index of List A.

So after the loop i want to have 2 identical lists.

I know this alone doesnt make much sense, but I also want to do different things in this loop I havent included here for simplification.

```
lista = ["apple", "banana", "pinapple", "kiwi", "orange"]
listb = ["apple", "pinapple", "kiwi"]

for i in range(len(lista)):
    if(lista[i] != listb[i]):
        listb.insert(i, lista[i])

print(listb)
```

When i run this, i get the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    if(lista[i] != listb[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why am I being an idiot here? I googled for the last 2 hours and am going mad.

Comment: When `i` becomes 4, your `listb` is `['apple', 'banana', 'pinapple', 'kiwi']`. So `listb[4]` doesn't exist.

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: Don't Google this kind of thing. [Debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it. Work out which list access is out of range (is it `lista[i]` or is it `listb[i]`?) then print out what that list contents are and what the value of `i` is at the time it fails, and use this information to work out which of your original assumptions about that list is incorrect.

Comment: These problems can often be solved quickly by simply printing all the relevant info during the loop. I did that and could immediately confirm that @not_speshal pointed you in the right direction. It doesn't take hours of googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lista` has indices from `0:4`, while `listb` has indices from `0:2`. Thus `3` and `4` are invalid indices for `listb` as initially defined, though this changes during the insertion process.

```
# Demonstration of indices
lista = ["apple", "banana", "pinapple", "kiwi", "orange"]
listb = ["apple", "pinapple", "kiwi"]

for i in range(len(lista)):
    print(i)
    try:
        print(f'element {i} of list a = {lista[i]}')
    except: 
        print(f'{i} is an invalid index for list a')
    try:
        print(f'element {i} of list b = {listb[i]}')
    except:
        print(f'{i} is an invalid index for list b')
```

Result:

```
element 0 of list a = apple
element 0 of list b = apple
element 1 of list a = banana
element 1 of list b = pinapple
element 2 of list a = pinapple
element 2 of list b = kiwi
element 3 of list a = kiwi
3 is an invalid index for list b
element 4 of list a = orange
4 is an invalid index for list b
```

One potential solution to your task, assuming there is a reason you need to compare and insert values:

```
for i, v in enumerate(lista):
    if v not in listb:
        listb.insert(i, v)

print(lista)
print(listb)
```

```
['apple', 'banana', 'pinapple', 'kiwi', 'orange']
['apple', 'banana', 'pinapple', 'kiwi', 'orange']
```

Comment: 3 becomes a valid index during the process (`"banana"` is inserted), but 4 isn't.

Comment: @Axe319 I did. `listb = ['apple', 'banana', 'pinapple', 'kiwi']` before the error. Index 3 becomes valid in the process.

Comment: This fails to reproduce duplicates such as `["apple", "banana", "pinapple", "kiwi", "orange","orange"]`

Comment: Thanks, you were a great help!

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists of different sizes. The length of the first one (`lista`) is 5, meaning that there are 5 elements in it. The length of the second one (`listb`) is 3. The `i` variable in your for loop will go through all values returned by the `range(len(lista))` function, which is really `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. As the length of your second list is only 3 that means it will raise errors when asked for an element at index greater than 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = ["apple", "banana", "pinapple", "kiwi", "orange"]
listb = ["apple", "pinapple", "kiwi"]

for item in lista:
    if item not in listb:
        listb.insert(lista.index(item),item)

print(listb)
```

Changes:

- len() function is inappropriately used, as you are not iterating length, but indexes, now the script iterates through every item in lista
- checks if item is in listb, if not, inserts item at lista's index of that item
- that's all there is to it!

Hope this helps, but really, try debugging instead of googling next time :)

Comment: What happens when there are 2 items with an identical name in the `list`?